# Exception: FILE NOT FOUND - Deploying C++ app on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, windows-server-2008-r2

**The Problem:** C++/CLI application is throwing file not found exception on **windows server 2008 R2** because msvcr120.dll is not available in system32 folder. Instead, there is file with name *msvcr120_clr0400*. Vc++ 2012 update 4 and .net framework 4.5.2 is installed on **windows server.**

**Exception Details:**

a few details of exception:

Problem Event: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 8: 124
Problem Signature 9: file not found exception

**Application build configs:**

visual studio 2013
x86
release
.net 4.5
vc++ 2012

**Dependencies:** checked from *dumpbin* utility

*kernel32.dll*

*MSVCR120.dll*

*MSVCP120.dll*

*mscoree.dll* [ from windows/system32 folder ]

opencv dlls and some other dlls - resides in exe folder.

Now, my Questions are that 
**is there any difference between deploying c++ application to windows server and on other end-user windows editions?** 
**should I install Vc++ 2012 [without update] as well?**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the wrong version of Visual C++ Redistributable Package. Depending on your opencv version I think you need a different version vcredist.

Edit:
msvcr120.dll is part of Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: opencv version is 2.4.10